# Gradle Maven like multi module project

Tags: gradle, multi-module

When you define multi module project in Maven, you have one root project and its modules. When you build the root project, Maven transitivelly builds all its modules in correct order. So far pretty similar to Gradle.

But with Maven, you can clone only one submodule from repository and build it locally without need to download the whole project structure. This is because you define dependencies on other modules within the same project just as any other external dependency and it is downloaded and cached from your local repository (Nexus).

With Gradle, you define cross module dependencies as `compile project(':other')`. So you need to clone whole project structure from repository in order to resolve and build correctly. Is there any way to use Gradle multi module project support, without having to locally clone whole project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that Maven's multi-module support is a slapped on after-thought. Unlike Gradle, a project dependency is not a first class concept. Instead the maven "reactor" substitutes local artifacts for dependencies when the GAV (group/artifact/version) matches.

If you'd like to use the same approach in Gradle then you can specify your dependencies using the GAV notation and then use the new [composite build feature](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) to join two or more separate gradle builds together and substitute repository dependencies for local source dependencies. Note that that you can define the projects included in the composite using groovy so you could easily script this based on custom logic (eg if a subfolder exists in some root folder etc)

Note that composite build support is a [new feature added in Gradle 3.1](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes#composite-builds). Prior to Gradle 3.1 you can use [Prezi Pride](https://github.com/prezi/pride) to achieve the same