# How child project can have root project as dependency in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have multi project gradle configuration.

at settings.gradle i have

```
include 'childProject folder'
```

I would like to have access to code from the root project in child project so in child build.gradle i added

```
dependencies {
    compile: rootProject
```

}

Intelij Idea recognizes this and in src files of child i have access to code from root project, however `gradle build` fails because code from root project is not included during compile of child
What is wrong with my config?

Comment: Maybe a good answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528029/gradle-maven-like-multi-module-project) I have used reactor with Maven and Gradle is similar in principle

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this in your submodule's `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':rootProject')
}
```

Comment: I tried. However the right syntax is `compile project(':')` and it does not work too. In child project i get only access to transitive deps of the root project but not to the code of the root